# gdb uses wrong library, but sysroot declared

Tags: debugging, gdb, cross-platform

I run a cross debug session with GDB. GDB is configured with option --with-sysroot, how described in the docs. My Application uses shared libraries like the following.

Code:

```
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x40026000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x40046000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x400b9000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x400c4000)
    libts-0.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/libts-0.0.so.0 (0x400d3000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0x4015f000)
    libz.so.1 => /usr/lib/libz.so.1 (0x401d3000)
    libjpeg.so.8 => /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.8 (0x401ee000)
```

The libraries pthread, libdl, ... are found in my toolchain, declared by *set sysroot*, *--with-sysroot* and *set solib-absolute-path*
The libraries libts, libz, ... are available in my additional path for shared libraries, declared in session with *set solib-search-path*

For the libraries libfreetype, libjpeg the following error occurs:

> 102,416 &"warning: `/usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6': Shared library architecture unknown is not compatible with target architecture arm.\n"
>   102,416 =library-loaded,id="/usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6",target-name="/usr/liblibfreetype.so.6",host-name="/usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6",symbols-loaded="0",thread-group="i1"

The reason GDB **still** takes libraries of host rootfs, once not found in the toolchain, and available in host rootfs. It doesn't care about my additional path declared with *set solib-search-path*

I configured GDB with --with-sysroot, declared additional *set sysroot*, *set solib-search-path*, *set solib-absolute-path* (nevermind alias of *set sysroot*).

In the docu, *--prefix* configures GDB to take the sysroot autmatically, but why this is higher prior than *--with-sysroot*?

Is GDB using the order *sysroot*, *host-sysroot*, *solib-search-path*?

**What** i missed to tell GDB, not to use the host rootfs?

Comment: "I'm guessing this use case wasn't originally considered, because it doesn't
look like how set sysroot/solib-search-path are meant to be used.

(gdb) help set solib-search-path 
Set the search path for loading non-absolute shared library symbol files.
This takes precedence over the environment variables PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. ... IOW, make the sysroot wholly self contained
(you can use symlinks though), and forget about solib-search-path." - http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13989

Answer (score 0):

There is a gdb bug tracking the very same issue http://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=13989

It is not fixed until version gdb-7.4. So, I think this behavior is expected with previous versions.